# Calculate SUM of particular values in one row even if some of them have NULL value

Tags: sql-server

This is for example my table:

```
 CodeID YEAR    Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Avgs    Sep Oct Nov Decm
 --------------------------------------------------------------------
 0406384    2014    20  14  14  12  NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL
 0406384    2013    11  NULL 22 13  13  16  14  39  24  20  16  16  215
```

I want  to create a query to calculate total sum of all months for each year and add that value in a new column (SUM_YEAR). If I have some NULL values it should be ignored. So the result will be:

```
CodeID  YEAR    Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Avgs    Sep Oct Nov Decm SUM_YEAR
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0406384 2014    20  14  14  12  NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 60
0406384 2013    11  NULL 22 13  13  16  14  39  24  20  16  16  204
```

How this could be accomplished ?

Comment: like this, `isnull(value,0)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into table (SUM_YEAR) (

SELECT sum(IsNull(Jan,0)) 
         + IsNull(Feb,0) 
......
AS SUM_YEAR FROM table)
```

Answer (score 0):

Zero out the null values in the calculation. e.g.

```
    SELECT
        SUM(COALESCE(some_column, 0)) AS SUM_YEAR
```